# Clamping FPS with gettimeofday

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I'm trying to clamp my game loop to a specific FPS by employing gettimeofday. It's a very rudimentary game, so it keeps chewing up all my processing power.

Regardless of how low I set my FRAMES_PER_SECOND, it continues to try to run as fast as possible.

I got a pretty good handle on what deWiTTERS has to say about game loops, but am using gettimeofday instead of GetTickCount b/c I'm on a Mac.

Also, I'm running OSX and using C++, GLUT.

This is what my main looks like:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (true)
    {
    timeval t1, t2;
    double elapsedTime;
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL); // start timer

    const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30;
    const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
    double next_game_tick = elapsedTime;
    int sleep_time = 0;

    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH); 
    glutInitWindowSize (windowWidth, windowHeight); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("A basic OpenGL Window"); 
    glutDisplayFunc (display); 
    glutIdleFunc (idle); 
    glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMovement); //check for mouse movement
    glutMouseFunc(buttonPress); //check for button press

    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL); // stop timer after one full loop
    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // compute sec to ms
    elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // compute us to ms

    next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
    sleep_time = next_game_tick - elapsedTime;
    if( sleep_time >= 0 )
        {
        sleep( sleep_time );
        }

    glutMainLoop (); 
    }
}
```

I've tried placing my gettimeofday and sleep functions in multiple locations, but I can't seem to find the sweet spot for them (given that my code is even correct).

Comment: If you're using GLUT why aren't you using `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)`?

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. I was hoping to use an alternative to GLUT someday down the road, and I figure if I begin with at least making my timer-funcs non-GLUT specific, that would be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will only ever get called once. You need to put the FPS logic inside the display function I believe because glutMainLoop will never return. (which also means your while loop is not needed. )

edit: or more likely it should go inside your idle function. It has been awhile since I have used glut.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I moved my entire FPS code to my glutIdleFunc, however - the program craps out upon running it... I was under the impression that I had to separate `gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);` and `gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);` with perhaps my glutDisplayFunc?

Comment: Update1: I have moved all of my FPS code to glutIdleFunc (as you suggested above). I can get the program to run, however, only if I comment out my `if( sleep_time >= 0 )` statement. Perhaps my `sleep` code is screwy?

Comment: Update2: I've changed `sleep( sleep_time );` to `usleep( sleep_time );` b/c I am dealing with microseconds. No longer freezing on me at least :) Nevertheless, even when changing my `FRAMES_PER_SECOND` to `5`, I see no change in framerate as the program continues to run at breakneck speed. Still trying.

Comment: Update3: FIXED - THANKYOU! :) B/c I am now calculating my sleep in microseconds, i had to multiply the sleep_time itself: `usleep( sleep_time * 1000 )` Thank you, Thank you, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[`glutMainLoop()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html):

> `glutMainLoop` enters the GLUT event processing loop. **This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program.** Once called, **this routine will never return**. It will call as necessary any callbacks that have been registered.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. I removed the while loop altogether inside of main. Thank you. Also, I'm trying to move the rest of the FPS code into glutIdleFunc. Still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you initialise `next_game_tick` from `elapsed_time` you haven't yet initialised `elapsed_time`.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I've gone ahead and initialized `elapsedTime` to an arbitrary value: `float elapsedTime = 1;` However, after moving the FPS code into glutIdleFunc, the program is freezing on me. Still trying. Thank you.